# Angular Listing all days between two dates

Tags: angular

Angular 7 :  Listing all days between two dates(range: [date start, enddate]) ,

I would like to list  all days between two date (range) in angular 7 .
please help me !!

Comment: Hi Gritli welcome to SO, please take a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getDaysBetweenDates(startDate,endDate) {
    var sDate = new Date(startDate);
    var eDate = new Date(endDate);
    var diff = Math.round((eDate-sDate)/(1000*60*60*24));
    var dayMap = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
    var dates = [];
    while(diff > -1) {
        dates.push(dayMap[new Date(sDate).getDay()]);
        sDate.setDate(sDate.getDate()+1);
        diff--;
    }
    return dates;
}
```

Use Like :-

```
getDaysBetweenDates("05/Jun/2020","08/Jun/2020");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is not Angular related, you can achieve this using plain Javascript
you need to iterate through the date range and just keep adding 1 day until you reach the end day.

```
   const allDays = []; //array for range dates

   var startDate=new Date();
   var endDate = new Date();

   endDate.setMonth(endDate.getMonth() + 1); // this is only for illustration

   //we are iterating through date and pushing them to the alldays
   while(startDate < endDate){

     startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);

     allDays.push(startDate);
   }
  console.log(allDays);
```